# Every measurable subset of measure space is new measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $E\in \mathfrak{M}$. Prove that $E$ is also measure space.

**Proof:** $(E,\mathfrak{M}_E,\bar\mu)$ be a measure space where $\bar \mu$ is "old" measure $\mu$ which is rectricted on $\mathfrak{M}_E$.
But how to define $\mathfrak{M}_E$?
Rudin says that $\mathfrak{M}_E:=\{A\in \mathfrak{M}: A\subset E\}$.

Unfortunately I can't show that it's  the $\sigma$-algebra.

$1)$ It's easy to see that $\varnothing \in \mathfrak{M}_E$.

$2)$ Let $A \in \mathfrak{M}_E$ how to prove that $A^c\in \mathfrak{M}_E$?

$3)$ If $A_i \in \mathfrak{M}_E$ then $\bigcup \limits_{i\geqslant 1}A_i\in \mathfrak{M}_E$. It's also obvious.

How to prove the second property? Since $A\in \mathfrak{M}_E$ then $A\in \mathfrak{M}$ and $A\subset E$. Then $A^c \in \mathfrak{M}$ but $A^c$ is not subset of $E$.

Comment: You have to prove that $E\setminus A \subset E$, not that $A^C \subset E$. Remember that the setting is taking place in $E$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein, You mean that I must consider complement of sets relative to $E$? Why?

Comment: Because you want to prove that this is a sigma algebra on $E$

Comment: @AhmedHussein, Yes! Then $\mathfrak{M}_E$ must be another not like mine. Right?

Comment: I did not understand the question. Are you asking whether $\mathfrak{M}_E$ should be something other than that defined in the post?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, Yes exactly. P.S. Sorry for my English :(

Comment: No worries. No, it should be exactly as defined here. It is a sigma algebra for the reasons you outlined and because $E \setminus A$ is obviously $\subset E$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein, Thanks a lot!